# reserve and then assign to a std::string

Tags: c++

If I resize and then assign a std::string as follows

```
std::string str;
str.resize(4);
str[1] = 'A'; // No problem
```

there shouldn't be problems, but if I reserve and then assign

```
std::string str;
str.reserve(4);
str[1] = 'A'; // ?
```

will there be problems? I read that the elements are left uninitialized and that the size isn't increased. Does it make sense to assign with the [] operator to an element then?

Comment: The second makes no sense and is undefined behavior.

Comment: Could you expand on your answer please? I can't still understand what's wrong

Comment: `I read that the elements are left uninitialized and that the size isn't increased` - you answered your own question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/reserve/)

> By reserving a capacity for the string of at least the size of the entire file, we try to avoid all the automatic reallocations that the object str could suffer each time that inserting a new character would make its length surpass its capacity.

`reserve` doesn't increase the size of the string, just say how much it need to increase the next time it requires when make a reallocation.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string::reserve` allocates but does not initialize memory (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/reserve/); that is - it requests `capacity`. However, it does not affect `size`, so

```
std::string s;
s.reserve(1000);
s[0] = 'a';
```

is illegal, because the string is zero length so `s[0]` accesses beyond the current end of string.

According to the spec, `resize` optionally takes an argument that is a fill character:

```
std::string s;
s.resize(1000, ' ');
```

if omitted, then the string is padded with null bytes, equivalent to

```
s.resize(1000, '\0');
```

while it is now legal to do

```
s[0] = 'a';
```

the following is non-sensical because it generates an invalid c-string; the first byte is 0 and thus the terminator.

```
std::string s;
s.resize(1000, '\0'); // or s.resize(1000);
s[1] = 'a'; // s[0] is 0 and thus as a c-string [1] is beyond eos.
```

`std::string::operator[]` is not required to observe or check `size`, the following is UB:

```
std::string s;
s.resize(8);
char a = s[9];  // beyond length, may crash, may return garbage.
```

Answer (score 0):

`reserve` just reserves space for the string to expand into. It does *not* expand the string into that space. Trying to use an element before the string has expanded so that element is part of the string leads to undefined behavior.

I'd probably use something like this:

```
str.reserve(4);
str.push_back('A');
```

Note that this sets `str[0]` to `A` though, not `str[1]`. To set a value in `str[1]`, you must also (one way or another) initialized `str[0]`.